# SQL Query if appears more that once in one table display the other table data

Tags: sql

Im trying to get the OwnerID, FName, LName from Owner when the OwnerID appears more than once in Property. This is what i tried but im pretty new to sql so i don't know if this is even close.

```
Select OwnerID, FName, LName 
From Owner 
Where OwnerID = (Select OwnerID 
                 From Property 
                 GROUP BY OwnerID 
                 HAVING Count(*) >=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
Select OwnerID, FName, LName 
From Owner 
Where OwnerID In (Select OwnerID 
                 From Property 
                 Group By OwnerID 
                 Having Count(OwnerId) >= 2)
```

But if you are trying to get all owners who own more than 1 property, that assumes that a property always has only a single owner, which is not always the case in the real world.

Comment: When i enter that i get the error "Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: better use IN rather than "="

Answer (score 2):

You can use IN operator like @Mitch Wheat answer, or use EXISTS :

```
Select OwnerID, FName, LName 
From Owner a
Where EXISTS (Select b.OwnerID 
                 From Property b
                 WHERE a.OwnerID = b.OwnerID
                 Group By b.OwnerID 
                 Having Count(b.OwnerId) >= 2)
```

Comment: Perhaps mention to OP, that you are using a correlated sub-query...?

Answer (score 1):

by performace I would do

```
Select OwnerID, FName, LName 
From Owner a
Where EXISTS (Select *
             From Property b
             WHERE a.OwnerID = b.OwnerID
             Group By b.OwnerID 
             Having Count(*) >= 2)
```